# What the meaning of these messages in the output of NetBeans C++ 8.0.2?

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans

I run a "Hello World" in NetBeans C++, it runs properly, but in the output theres the error mesages:

```
Hello World! 
read from master failed
                                    : Input/output error

RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 72ms)
```

What does this mean and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change a default-selected terminal type. To do so, go to

`Properties` *(right-click on your project)* -> `Run` -> `Console type`

and change the type. The problem sometimes occurs when a selected option is other than `Standard output` (I assume that's your case).